# Scope of <Plug>(coc-references) don't search on entire project folder

Tags: c++, vim-plugin, coc.nvim

Using coc.vim feature (coc-references) on the name of classA or any other one, it seems to search and find references only on local file ClassA.cpp, not on entire project folders' sources.

> ProjecT-Root
> SubfolderA/classA.cpp
> SubfolderB/classB.cpp
> classeC.cpp calling new classA

The command (coc-references) report me only classA.cpp occurrences.

I would like all references reported on entire project. If i use coc-references-used, it's the same.

Thank you
Nicolas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's language server's issue, `coc-references` requests `textDocument/references` to language server, LS returns results and coc.nvim display them.